# Why do I get an empty list after a recursive function?

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
subset = []
subsets = []


def search(k, n):
    if k == n and subset:
        subsets.append(subset)
    else:
        search(k + 1, n)
        subset.append(k)
        search(k + 1, n)
        del subset[-1]


search(0, 5)
```

This is supposed to store all of the nonempty subsets of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in the list `subsets`.

I got that `subsets` is a list of empty lists, but I expected subsets to be a list of all nonempty subsets of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I also tried to place the `global` keyword in before the function. Am I doing something wrong? (I know that in Java the problem was solved by adding the `new` keyword in front of the subset, so I would use `subsets.add(new ArrayList<>(subset))`. But in python, I don't think this problem exists)

Comment: Please provide the output you expect from `search(0, 5)`

Comment: I put in the text: "but I expected subsets to be a list of all nonempty subsets of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]."

Comment: Ok, I get a recursion error when running the code you provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do, in fact, need to make a copy of the `subset` list just like you would in Java for essentially the same reasons. (Otherwise, you're just adding the same reference to the result multiple times and all updates are reflected in each of them.)

```py
if k == n:
    if subset:
        subsets.append(list(subset))
else:
    search(k + 1, n)
    subset.append(k)
    search(k + 1, n)
    del subset[-1]
```

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for a simpler solution.

```py
import itertools
def non_empty_subsequences(l):
    return [list(s) for i in range(1, len(l) + 1) for s in itertools.combinations(l, i)]
print(non_empty_subsequences(range(1,6)))
```